# How can I tell whether a brand of drywall mud is lightweight?

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

Even though the label on [this product](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/sheetrock-cgc-all-purpose-drywall-compound-ready-mixed-12-l-pail/1000113385) says it's "conventional weight", is it considered to be lightweight?

Comment: What is the problem you’re trying to solve? Are you trying to find a topping mud?

Comment: If it's lightweight it'll say lightweight. Why the distrust?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, yes I'm looking for a topping mud. I've read that normally all-purpose lightweight mud is recommended. So I'll need the actual "lit"e product, not the "conventional weight".

Comment: Topping mud is only available in large boxes around here, but I’d still buy it and waste a bunch in order to get what topping mud offers. I’ve never met an AP that acts like real topping.

Answer (score 1):

No, [Total](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-sheetrock-total-drywall-compound-ready-mixed-17-l-carton/1001057376) is mid-grade, [All Purpose Lite](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en_CA_east/products/walls/drywall/joint-compound/ready-mix-drywall-compounds/sheetrock-all-purpose-lite-drywall-compound.html) and [Lite weight taping](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en_CA_east/products/walls/drywall/joint-compound/ready-mix-drywall-compounds/sheetrock-lite-weight-taping-compound.html) are even lighter.